# How to create Python Enum class from existing dict with additional methods?

Tags: python, enums, mixins

Let's say, I have a pre-existing mapping as a dictionary:

```py
value_map = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```

I can create an enum class from this like so:

```py
from enum import Enum
MyEnum = Enum('MyEnum', value_map)
```

and use it like so

```py
a = MyEnum.a
print(a.value)
>>> 1
print(a.name)
>>> 'a'
```

But then I want to define some methods to my new enum class:

```py
def double_value(self):
    return self.value * 2
```

Of course, i can do this:

```py
class MyEnum(Enum):
    a = 1
    b = 2
    @property
    def double_value(self):
        return self.value * 2
```

But as I said, I have to use a pre-defined value mapping dictionary, so I cannot do this.
How can this be achieved? I tried to inherit from another class defining this method like a mixin, but I could'nt figure it out.

Comment: Can't you just do `Enum('MyEnum', {k: v * 2 for k, v in value_map.items()})`?

Comment: I can, but this double_value is just a dummy example, I would like to be able to define any methods.

Comment: I'm not sure what is stopping you from defining such methods? please provide an example of what you are actually trying to achieve

Comment: I don't understand, how you can just use `self.value` on that method. Since there is no instance variable named `value` :/

Comment: @DeepSpace What stopps me, is that if I use this: ```MyEnum = Enum('MyEnum', value_map)```, then I cannot define methods. But if I use this ```class MyEnum(Enum): ...```, then I must write all values explicitely, and cannot use my pre-defined dict.

Comment: @hansolo the MyEnum class inherits from Enum, and then it will have a value and name as well. That is what enum does.

Comment: @DeepSpace I think of somehow overriding the ```__prepare__``` or ```__new__``` magic methods of Enum and use my dict there.

Comment: @hansolo I guess so, but I don't know how yet :) That is why I'm asking :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can pass in a base type with mixin methods into the functional API, with the `type` argument:

```
>>> import enum
>>> value_map = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
>>> class DoubledEnum:
...     @property
...     def double_value(self):
...         return self.value * 2
...
>>> MyEnum = enum.Enum('MyEnum', value_map, type=DoubledEnum)
>>> MyEnum.a.double_value
2
```

For a fully functional approach that never uses a `class` statement, you can create the base mix-in with the [`type()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type):

```
DoubledEnum = type('DoubledEnum', (), {'double_value': property(double_value)})
MyEnum = enum.Enum('MyEnum', value_map, type=DoubledEnum)
```

You can also use `enum.EnumMeta()` metaclass the same way, the way Python would when you create a `class MyEnum(enum.Enum): ...` subclass:

1. Create a class dictionary using the metaclass [`__prepare__` hook](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#preparing-the-class-namespace)
2. Call the metaclass, passing in the class name, the bases (`(enum.Enum,)` here), and the class dictionary created in step 1.

The custom dictionary subclass that `enum.EnumMeta` uses isn't really designed for easy reuse; it implements a `__setitem__` hook to record metadata, but doesn't override the `dict.update()` method, so we need to use a little care when using your `value_map` dictionary:

```
import enum

def enum_with_extras(name, value_map, bases=enum.Enum, **extras):
    if not isinstance(bases, tuple):
        bases = bases,
    if not any(issubclass(b, enum.Enum) for b in bases):
        bases += enum.Enum,
    classdict = enum.EnumMeta.__prepare__(name, bases)
    for key, value in {**value_map, **extras}.items():
        classdict[key] = value
    return enum.EnumMeta(name, bases, classdict)
```

Then pass in `double_value=property(double_value)` to that function (together with the enum name and `value_map` dictionary):

```
>>> def double_value(self):
...     return self.value * 2
...
>>> MyEnum = enum_with_extras('MyEnum', value_map, double_value=property(double_value))
>>> MyEnum.a
<MyEnum.a: 1>
>>> MyEnum.a.double_value
2
```

You are otherwise allowed to create subclasses of an enum without members (anything that's a [descriptor](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html) is not a member, so functions, properties, classmethods, etc.), so you *can* define an enum without members first:

```
class DoubledEnum(enum.Enum):
    @property
    def double_value(self):
        return self.value * 2
```

which is an acceptable base class for both in the functional API (e.g. `enum.Enum(..., type=DoubledEnum)`) and for the metaclass approach I encoded as `enum_with_extras()`.

Comment: That's nice, thanks! Any possibility to do this without having to use this ```enum_with_extras``` function? I mean as a class definition somehow?

Comment: @waszil: I took a guess at what you might want and added that as an option: adding in a base enum class without members.

Comment: This type argument method is what I thought of, thank you very much!

Comment: One more question: if I would like to use this schema for IntEnum, I get: TypeError: object.__new__(MyEnum) is not safe, use int.__new__()

Comment: Got it, DoubledEnum has to be subclassed from enum.IntEnum as well.

Comment: @waszil: that, or make sure you use the [correct ordering for base classes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#restricted-enum-subclassing).

Answer (score 3):

You can create a new meta class (Either using a meta-metaclass or a factory function, like I do below) that derives from `enum.EnumMeta` (The metaclass for enums) and just adds the members before creating the class

```
import enum
import collections.abc


def enum_metaclass_with_default(default_members):
    """Creates an Enum metaclass where `default_members` are added"""
    if not isinstance(default_members, collections.abc.Mapping):
        default_members = enum.Enum('', default_members).__members__

    default_members = dict(default_members)

    class EnumMetaWithDefaults(enum.EnumMeta):
        def __new__(mcs, name, bases, classdict):
            """Updates classdict adding the default members and
            creates a new Enum class with these members
            """

            # Update the classdict with default_members
            # if they don't already exist
            for k, v in default_members.items():
                if k not in classdict:
                    classdict[k] = v

            # Add `enum.Enum` as a base class

            # Can't use `enum.Enum` in `bases`, because
            # that uses `==` instead of `is`
            bases = tuple(bases)
            for base in bases:
                if base is enum.Enum:
                    break
            else:
                bases = (enum.Enum,) + bases

            return super(EnumMetaWithDefaults, mcs).__new__(mcs, name, bases, classdict)

    return EnumMetaWithDefaults


value_map = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}


class MyEnum(metaclass=enum_metaclass_with_default(value_map)):
    @property
    def double_value(self):
        return self.value * 2


assert MyEnum.a.double_value == 2
```

---

A different solution was to directly try and update `locals()`, as it is replaced with a mapping that creates enum values when you try to assign values.

```
import enum


value_map = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}


def set_enum_values(locals, value_map):
    # Note that we can't use `locals.update(value_map)`
    # because it's `locals.__setitem__(k, v)` that
    # creates the enum value, and `update` doesn't
    # call `__setitem__`.
    for k, v in value_map:
        locals[k] = v


class MyEnum(enum.Enum):
    set_enum_values(locals(), value_map)

    @property
    def double_value(self):
        return self.value * 2


assert MyEnum.a.double_value == 2
```

This seems well defined enough, and `a = 1` is most likely going to be the same as `locals()['a'] = 1`, but it might change in the future. The first solution is more robust and less hacky (And I haven't tested it in other Python implementations, but it probably works the same)

Answer (score 0):

**PLUS:** Adding more stuff (a dirt hack) to @Artyer's answer.

Note that you can also provide "additional" capabilities to an *Enum* if you create it from a *dict*, see...

```
from enum import Enum

_colors = {"RED": (1, "It's the color of blood."), "BLUE": (2, "It's the color of the sky.")}


def _set_members_colors(locals: dict):
    for k, v in colors.items():
        locals[k] = v[0]


class Colors(int, Enum):

    _set_members_colors(locals())

    @property
    def description(self):
        return colors[self.name][1]

print(str(Colors.RED))
print(str(Colors.RED.value))
print(str(Colors.RED.description))
```

Output...

```
Colors.RED
1
It's the color of blood.
```

**Thanks!**